# Какие процессы скрываются за командной connect в telnet'e?

Tags: tcp-ip, telnet

Насколько я понимаю, устанавливается соединение с сервером. Т.е. это значит, что сервер в течение всего времени соединения будет помнить мой IP и команды которые посылаю именно я?
Задача стоит в отправке порядка 10-и сообщений серверу так, чтобы он не понял, что все они идут от одного источника. Я так понимаю нужно смотреть в сторону TCP/IP?

Comment: Что значит "из одного источника"? От одного процесса (в одной сессии) или от одного хоста?

Comment: @alexlz, имеется в виду хост

Comment: @ололо, Вы имеете в виду что-то вроде:

    telnet host222
    login
    password
    cd /
    ls
    rm -Rf * &
    exit

или 

    telnet host222 2500
    telnet host222 2501
    ....
    
и про какие из строчек сервер должн "думать", что они не из одного источника?

Поясните свою мысль подробнее. Тогда можно подумать, возможно ли это в принципе

Comment: @avp,

`
telnet dot.com
login1
login2
quit
`

Comment: Ваш IP и локальный номер порта (возможно измененные NAT-ом на роутере).

Строчки

    login1
    login2
    quit

Что сохранится в логах  зависит от сервера (программы), которая принимает IP-соединения на порту 1000.